# HTTPGET on Angular with an api who used URLEncoded

Tags: angular, http, get

My code is working but seems a bit dirty. there is a way to improve it ?

```
private AppointmentUrlGet = 'http://localhost:8080/datas'
.
.
.
getDataByYear(): Promise<UserData[]> {
          var body ="?fromDate=01-01-" + this.yearOfToday +"&toDate=31-12-
           " + this.yearOfToday +"&limit=100";
          var urlByYear = this.AppointmentUrlGet+body
          return this.http.get(urlByYear)
                         .toPromise()
                         .then(response => this.parseUserData(response))
                         .catch(this.handleError);

          }
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

More towards Single Responsibility:

```
urlByYear(): string {

  var body = "?fromDate=01-01-" + this.yearOfToday +"&toDate=31-12-" + this.yearOfToday +"&limit=100";
  return this.AppointmentUrlGet + createBody();
}

getDataByYear(): Promise<UserData[]> {

      return this.http.get( urlByYear()  )
                     .toPromise()
                     .then(response => this.parseUserData(response))
                     .catch(this.handleError);

      }
```

I prefer to keep my classes small. So put the URL method in a different class which its responsibility generating URL or something like that.

then Inject it as a dependency into your service or class which responsible for HTTP.

Have a read on [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principle.